# Azure Network Performance Monitor - Issue with discovering agents

Tags: azure

We have requirement to allow communication between SUSE Linux based VM located in Microsoft Azure and on premise SUSE Linux based server. Also need to configure NPM to detect network issues like traffic black holing, routing errors etc.

Steps:
We have configured NPM based on steps mentioned in below link. (also opened TCP in bound and out bound port 8084 for Azure SUSE Linux based VM).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-network-performance-monitor

Issue: As seen in screenshot 1, NPM workspace shows that 2 VM’s are connected (i.e. On premise and Azure VM’s) . 
However when “Discover Express Route Resources” is clicked, it doesn’t show any nodes. See screenshot 2 for reference. Even if you click on “Add Azure Agents”, there is no agent/node discovered.

Are we missing anything here?

[image: Screenshot 1][image]

Comment: Can you confirm if install OMS agent? allow 8084 port open inbound rule for Azure VM, allow any for the outbound rule?

Comment: OMS agent is already installed on SUSE VM. 8084 port has been opened/allowed for both inbound and outbound rule for Azure VM. I’m not entirely sure if “Any” is allowed for outbound rule of Azure VM. Could that be root cause of no nodes being displayed?

Comment: I mean by default, there are 3 outbound rules in NSG, you don't need to add additional out bound port 8084 for Azure SUSE Linux based VM).  You can try it.